# What is the difference between context switching and interrupt handling?

Tags: microcontroller, interrupts, linux, rtos, os

I'm an embedded developer. I haven't worked with RTOS/linux. I was going through RTOS concepts when I stumbled upon 'context switching'. I understand that when context switch occurs, all the registers along with PC(Program Counter) gets saved in stack before another thread is loaded to the processor. Isn't a similar thing happening when an interrupt occurs(in a controller which doesn't use any kind of  OS)?

How different are those two terms?

Comment: AFAIK, on most microcontrollers the context saving when an interrupt occurs happens in hardware while the context saving in an RTOS happens in software

Comment: An interrupt handler may not need to save all the thread state (having relatively little work to do). Some ISAs provide shadow/banked (MIPS/ARM) registers to avoid save/restore overhead or automatically save a limited amount of state (which is comparable to having such as shadow/banked registers). (Incidentally, MIPS MultiThreading Application Specific Extension extends Shadow Register Sets (31 GPRs) into Thread Contexts.) [Too short for an answer, but a quick response.]

Comment: each context usually has it's own stack allocated, so it's faster to switch to them than having to save all the register values onto the stack before switching and them pop them off after. The interrupt handlers in a microcontroller often have to do this manually in code, but if you use a RTOS on the microcontroller such as uCOS-II/III by Jean C Labrosse, each task/context has it's own stack and 'context'

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton can you elaborate your answer, i have no idea of how a thread runs only just a top level understanding. thanks though

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a fundamental difference, it's more a question of degree — the amount of context that needs to be saved.

When an RTOS thread context switch occurs, all of the CPU state that any thread might use must be saved. This usually includes all of the CPU registers, including flag or status registers, so that when they're restored, the thread resumes as though nothing ever happened.

When an interrupt occurs, there's still a context switch, but only the context that the interrupt handler actually needs to use needs to be saved and then subsequently restored. If you write your interrupt handler in a high-level language, this will pretty much be equivalent to a full thread context switch, because there are no constraints on what resources such an interrupt handler might touch. However, if you write your interrupt handler in assembly language, you can keep track of exactly which registers it touches and save only those. This allows the execution of the interrupt handler to be extremely fast, reducing its impact on the rest of the system, and/or allowing it to handle interrupts at a higher rate.

Comment: Even when an interrupt handler is written in a high-level language, if the handler doesn't call any outside code the compiler doesn't "know about", the compiler may be able to generate register save/restore code that ignores registers that aren't used by the interrupt handler itself.  Since the very nature of a "full" context switch is to allow the execution of arbitrary code, it must save/restore all registers whether or not the compiler is aware of anything that actually uses them.

Answer (score 2):

Both interrupts and context switches are interrupts.  The main difference is in what happens after the interrupt or context switch.

With an interrupt the current state (or context) is stored in a temporary area (usually, but not always, the stack).  The ISR then does its thing, and the state is then restored and the interrupt routine returns.  The crucial thing here is that the ISR returns *exactly where it left off* in the *same thread*.

A context switch looks just like an interrupt.  The state is stored in the stack as per usual.  However, the location of that stack and any extra state information is stored elsewhere (in the *thread*).  A new set of data from another thread is then substituted with the current data and the ISR returns.  Here though the ISR doesn't return to where it left off, but it returns to where the newly switched in thread was interrupted the last time a context switch occurred while it was running.

It's this change of return location and data that, besides what the content of the ISR may be, distinguishes an ISR form a context switch.

Answer (score 1):

an interrupt is a signal sent to a thread to indicate that it should stop what it is doing and perform some other task, while context switching is the process of saving the state of a currently executing thread and restoring the state of a different thread so that it can continue executing.